# How to get variable names and their values contained in a single string?

Tags: java, android, string, split

How to get string variable names and assign them values, if I have the information contained in a single string?

I have an string like this:

```
"id: 123487, street1: Stanton, street2: Gateway, street3: Hawkins, city: Horizon"
```

And the result that I'm trying to achieve is this:
id = "123487"
street1= "Stanton"
street2= "Gateway"
street3= "Hawkins"
city= "horizon"

What I have so far is this code:

```
String scannedData = "id: 123487, street1: Stanton, street2: Gateway, street3: Hawkins, city: Horizon"


String[] data = scannedData.split(",");
for (String result1 : data) {
    Toast.makeText(scanQrActivity.this,
            result1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

So I'm able to show to the user using the Toast is the separated string by commas, and I have this:
"id: 123487"
"street1: Stanton"
"street2: Gateway"
"street3: Hawkins"
"city: horizon"

Maybe I could previously create the 5 variables, and somehow only get the values, so in the for cycle I could assign each value to each variable?
But I'm not sure how, can you help me to achieve what 'm trying to do?
Thanks!

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you are asking, but you can further split the "str: Fnord" String down to an array of two Strings again.

Comment: Ok, I see, I'm trying to create string variables and assign them values, for example if I have this string:
"city: Horizon, street1: Stanton"
I want to have a string variable named city with its value equal to "Horizon" and do the same with street1 and so on.
So If I understood your suggestion was to split again. But this time split by ":"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `Location` class that will hold the data we're going to parse.

```
public class Location {

    private int id;

    private String street1, street2, street3, city;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreet1() {
        return street1;
    }

    public void setStreet1(String street1) {
        this.street1 = street1;
    }

    public String getStreet2() {
        return street2;
    }

    public void setStreet2(String street2) {
        this.street2 = street2;
    }

    public String getStreet3() {
        return street3;
    }

    public void setStreet3(String street3) {
        this.street3 = street3;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Now we can use the following method to parse the input string into a `Location` object.

```
public static Location parseLocation(String input) {
    // Get the input and split it into an array of "key: value" strings.
    String[] splitInput = input.split(", ");

    // Create an array to hold the actual key-values.
    String[][] keyValues = new String[splitInput.length][2];

    // Split each "key: value" string into its consisting parts.
    for (int i = 0; i < splitInput.length; i++) {
        keyValues[i] = splitInput[i].split(": ");
    }

    // Create a Location object to populate.
    Location location = new Location();

    // Find the keys & values from the input that you're looking for.
    for (String[] keyValue : keyValues) {

        // Switch on the key.
        switch (keyValue[0]) {
            case "id":
                location.setId(Integer.valueOf(keyValue[1]));
                break;

            case "street1":
                location.setStreet1(keyValue[1]);
                break;

            case "street2":
                location.setStreet2(keyValue[1]);
                break;

            case "street3":
                location.setStreet3(keyValue[1]);
                break;

            case "city":
                location.setCity(keyValue[1]);
                break;
        }
    }
    return location;
}
```

This solution allows for more key-values to be added to the input string without the program crashing. All you would need to do is add a case statement for the new key and add a getter / setter to the `Location` object.

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String   input    = "id: 123487, street1: Stanton, street2: Gateway, street3: Hawkins, city: Horizon";
    Location location = parseLocation(input);

    System.out.println(String.format("id: %d\n"
            + "street1: %s\n"
            + "street2: %s\n"
            + "street3: %s\n"
            + "city: %s", location.getId(), 
            location.getStreet1(), location.getStreet2(), 
            location.getStreet3(), location.getCity()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//'main' method must be in a class 'Rextester'.
//Compiler version 1.8.0_111

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Rextester
{  

        private static final String REGEX = ",";//"\\d";
                private static final String REGEX2 = ":";//"\\d";

    private static final String INPUT ="id: 123487, street1: Stanton, street2: Gateway, street3: Hawkins, city: Horizon";

        //"one9two4three7four1five";

    //public class SplitDemo2 {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        String[] items = p.split(INPUT);
        for(String s : items) {
            System.out.println(s);
            Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(REGEX2);
            String[] items2 = p2.split(s);
            for(String s2: items2){
                System.out.println(s2);
            }
        }
    }
//}

}//end Rextester
```

http://rextester.com/NZKDG47991

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, you gave me awesome suggestions, finally, I did it in a more simple way, it might not be the best coding, but I'm still learning, I think that my objective is to code like you guys, so your answers really help me to realize that there is so much for me to learn.

```
    String scannedData = "id: 123487, street1: Stanton, street2: Gateway, street3: Hawkins, city: Horizon"

    String[] data = scannedData .split(",");
    String id = null;
    String street1 = null;
    String street2 = null;
    String street3 = null;
    String city = null;
    for (String result : data) {

        id = data[0].replace("id: ", "");
        street1 = data[1].replace("street1: ", "");
        street2 = data[2].replace("street2: ", "");
        street3 = data[3].replace("street3: ", "");
        city = data[4].replace("city: ", "");
    }
```

Then I showed each variable using a Toast.